# Why exception occurs, but control changed also in an async task

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task

I tried a simple code to test task working in winform like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(Counting).ContinueWith(CheckTaskResult);
}

private void CheckTaskResult(Task task)
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
        //exception found
    }
}

public async Task Counting()
{
    var status = await Task.FromResult("Done");
    // why it works
    button1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

I certainly get errors in the `CheckTaskResult` function (everybody knows why), but strangely the `button1.Text` changed also.

Why does the error occur - did the control change at the same time?

Comment: Why aren't you doing `private async void button1_Click` and `await Counting();`

Comment: @CallumLinington I know why errors, I just want to know why text changed successfully.

Comment: Cross-threaded UI access *can* cause errors - but it's not contractually *obliged* to raise errors, nor to actually *prevent* code from *appearing* to operate correctly.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You mean that's by design? I told you I CANNOT do this, although I DID?